# Primefaces PickList Ajax notfiring on transfer event to bean

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, jsf-2, picklist

Hey StackOverflow community,
maybe you guys are able to help me out since im out of ideas.

Im using PrimeFaces 6.0

Problem:
My PickList is not firing an event so my Java code can't handle it.

My view.xhtml

```
<p:dialog header="Division" widgetVar="dialog2" id="divDialog"
                minHeight="400" minWidth="400" showEffect="pop" resizable="false">
                <h:form>
                    <p:pickList id="pickList"
                        value="#{workerViewController.wvm.explicitDivision}" var="divList"
                        itemLabel="#{divList}" itemValue="#{workerViewController.wvm.division}"
                        showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true">
                        <p:ajax event="transfer"
                            listener="#{workerViewController.onTransfer}" /> 
                    </p:pickList>
                </h:form>
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandButton value="Save Data"
                        actionListener="#{workerViewController.onDivisionSave()}" />


                    <p:commandButton value="Close" type="button"
                        onclick="PF('dialog2').hide()" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Reset"
                        update=":#{p:component('workerTable')}"
                        actionListener="#{workerViewController.resetFilter()}" />
                </h:form>


            </p:dialog>
```

I've tested around and if I move my SaveData button inside the upper form-tag it doesn't fire events anymore as well.

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@Scope(value = "request")
@Controller
public class WorkerViewController {
....
    public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event){
        System.out.println("Write smthing");
        //this.wvm.onTransfer(evt);
    }
}
```

My only idea of the issue source right now is related to the Dialog which is inside of a tabview but all other actionListeners anywhere else in the code work.

Thanks already guys

Comment: Offtopic: managedbean and controller on one class is asking for trouble

Comment: Might I ask you to further explain why that is the case? Im quite new to Java as server side language and eager to learn

Comment: I added the transfer ajax but it seems to get lost in the request, did you manage to fix this?